# IIS server routing and redirection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, iis-7.5

In our IIS server we created 3 websites, so under the folder Sites we have `Default Web Site`, `Site1`, `Site 2`. under Default Web Site we have many many applications and one of these applications called "`Main`"

Also we have 1 domain name like "`http://www.ourdomain.com`"

How can I do the following

1. If the user wrote `http://www.ourdomain.com` or `http://www.ourdomain.com/main`, then redirect to **Default Web
   Site/Main**
2. If the user wrote `http://www.ourdomain.com/Site1`, then to show the content of `Site1` and not an application inside the `Default Web Site`
3. If the user wrote `http://www.ourdomain.com/Site2`, then to show the content of `Site2`

Our Admin he used the HTTP Redirect and he put the url `http://www.ourdomain.com/main` so everything is redirecting to main

Also, is it possible to use this configuration `site1.ourdomain.com` instead of `http://www.ourdomain.com/site1` ? and how if yes?

Forgive me for my question, I have no experience about how to work on these things in IIS

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

To get `site1.ourdomain.com` you just need to set the host header in IIS to use this subdomain. Right click the site in IIS, click "Edit Bindings", either add or edit an existing binding to use the subdomain. I would strongly recommend against having three separate sites in IIS if those sites are subsites.

[image]

### Option 2

Your other option would be to make the subsites `areas` in MVC in one project.

Comment: Unable to determine IP address from host name "site1.ourdomain.com"

Comment: Is that what you get when you put that url in the address bar? You have to point either a wildcard "`*`" or `site1` A record in your DNS settings for that to work. This question is probably better suited for Server Fault

Comment: any article or reference to read to give me hint or something?

Comment: @HadiHassan In addition to configuring IIS you'll need to configure an `A` record in your DNS settings. The record will follow the format, `Type  Name  Value  TTL` (or Time To Live). An example `A` record that would work with your subdomain would be `A  site1  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  600 seconds` where the `x`'s are replaced with the corresponding IP address numbers. With a specific subdomain like `site1` you can alternately create a `CNAME` to an alias instead of an IP. Note however, that if you take the wildcard approach you must use an `A` record with a dedicated IP address.